# Is there a way to locate Strategic Resources on the map?

Tags: civilization-5

When you first research a technology that reveals a new resource on the map (eg. [Electricity](http://civilopedia5.com/technologies/electricity.html) reveals [Aluminum](http://civilopedia5.com/resources/aluminum.html)), you can click the tip that comes up to center the map on deposits of that resource that are near your cities.

**Is there a way to easily find those Strategic Resources again on later turns?** So far I haven't found any method other than hovering my mouse over all of the tiles near where I thought it was to try to locate it.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can turn on the "resource icon" overlay which will put up floating icons showing what all the resources are (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, or click on the "toggle map options" button to the left of the mini-map and tick "resource icons").
If you then zoom out you should be able to see where the resources are quite easily, and what they are.

Comment: To help find said button: http://i.imgur.com/a4eZObc.png

Answer (score 8):

Whoward's strategic view Overlay Resources mod is useful for this: http://www.picknmixmods.com/mods/f2968890-fe71-41d4-b609-805097365935/mod.html

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the resource icons you can go to strategic view and select show resource overlay, this will show all strategic resources (coal,iron,...) in blue. I find it a little easier than the normal icons in the world view.