# How can I keep track of discovered antiquity sites?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-brave-new-world

It's easy to lose track of antiquities sites after discovering them.  Is there an easy way of finding them?

Maybe a UI mod to highlight them?

The best bet I've found as part of the default UI is to show resources in the strategic view, but this isn't great:

[image: Screenshot of map with resources shown]

Related question: [Is there a way to locate Strategic Resources on the map?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/74853/is-there-a-way-to-locate-strategic-resources-on-the-map)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've had a crack at implementing my first Civ mod to solve this problem: http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=169154575

Currently a bit of quick and dirty hack, but it works.  It adds another menu item "Antiquity Sites Only", which as you can here means that only Antiquity sites resource icons are shown.

[image: http://cloud-2.steampowered.com/ugc/1117177693909524866/C4B25559BD073891944D975BC14764F1105D5802/]

Source code: https://github.com/therefromhere/Civ5AntiquityIconsMod

Answer (score 2):

Yeah I have trouble with that as well. I use the 'Show Resource Icon' button (Ctrl + R) to help locate the sites but it gets a bit messy with a large number of resources in play. Hope this helps you out a bit but it's definitely not the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use Whoward's Overlay Resources mod: http://www.picknmixmods.com/mods/f2968890-fe71-41d4-b609-805097365935/mod.html

[image]